# Firefox 10 wont play webm videos. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, firefox, webm

I have a small webm video that plays fine in Chrome, but not firefox.  here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>html5 video</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video  controls="controls">
    <source  type="video/webm" src="file.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp80, vorbis"'/>
    Your browser cannot play this
    </video>
    <a href="file.webm">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I read somewhere that to get firefox to play webm, the .htaccess file need to be appended with this:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
```

So far nothing.  If I drag the file into firefox it plays fine.  This is the codec used according to VLC

```
Google/On2's VP8 Video (VP8)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a site we can look at?

Comment: running on a closed lan at the moment...would posting my full html be better?

Comment: Is this piece of code is working in chrome?. Check by providing absolute url & try.

Comment: @PraveenVijayan yes this piece is working in chrome

Comment: did you check by giving absolute url (http://domain.com/video.webm)?

Comment: @PraveenVijayan Firefox tries to download it, chrome plays it

Comment: okay fine. Then it must be the problem with server setting. Check you have added webm in MIME type - http://bignosebird.com/apache/a1.shtml

Comment: just added video/webm  webm to /etc/mime.types.  Is that right?  Its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was an improperly configured web server.  Following the instructions [here](http://bignosebird.com/apache/a1.shtml) and then rebooting all webm videos play fine in firefox.